# Manual linebreak and formatting docbook

Tags: xml, docbook

I am trying to make  a simple help with `Docbook`. I need to format the text rather than letting text to be compact and non readable. It is better if the text can be set as it is being typed (i.e: preserve white spaces and line breaks)

So far I tried  `<?line-break?>`, `<?lb?>` and `<sbr/>`. I only tried adding them to the position where I expect the line break as if using `"\n"` on C based language.

I am clueless of getting this done and I could not find any helpful resources. Any help appreciated regarding manual line break or formatting the text

```
<article xmlns='http://docbook.org/ns/docbook'>
    <title>Welcome to help</title>
    <section>
        <simplesect>
            <title>Abstract</title>
            <para>
              <!--Multi-lined paragraph where I 
                  need to break the lines manually
               -->
            </para>
        </simplesect>
    </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `Docbook` all the white space and line breaks can be preserved when using the tag `<literallayout>`. Where manual line breaks can also be done easily as if editing plain text!

```
<literallayout>
  O, for a muse of fire, that would ascend
The brightest heaven of invention!
A kingdom for a stage, princes to act,
And monarchs to behold the swelling scene!
</literallayout>
```

would give the output as,

[image]